# Fast conversion of array to string in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array of ~10,000 strings and integers that I want to serialize into a Rails web page. The eventual goal is to get the array into a JavaScript array, but I'm happy to just have it as a text blob that I then parse client side.

I can't cache the string, the values change every request.

This takes ~25ms on my VPS:

```
arr = ["ABCD", 1] * 10000 # always in string, number, string, number order
start = Time.now
arr.to_s
duration = (Time.now - start)*1000
puts "took #{duration}ms"
```

Can we do better?

**edit**

@sawa's answer is correct, `to_json` is fast and a good way to do this. I was getting thrown off because `to_json` in a Rails environment is overridden. Use `JSON.generate(arr)` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSON is faster as the array gets longer. As I tested with `["ABCD", 1] * n`, when approx `n < 50`, `to_s` is faster, but when `n > 50`, `to_json` is faster.

```
arr = ["ABCD", 1] * 10000 # always in string, number, string, number order

start = Time.now
arr.to_s
duration = (Time.now - start)*1000
puts "took #{duration}ms"

require "json"
start = Time.now
arr.to_json
duration = (Time.now - start)*1000
puts "took #{duration}ms"

# =>
# took 7.546628ms # to_s
# took 4.684186ms # to_json
```

Comment: aha! i was too tied up trying things in my rails environment. I believe rails overrides to_json to do some sanitation, switched to JSON.generate(arr) and I see timing similar to what we get in the contrived example. Thanks!